# Aggregating data percentage wise based on date related criteria from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have legacy tables which tracks flight and had to extract data. We have three tables named booking, airlines and flighttype. Note this is a dummy samples

**booking :**

| id | customer | request_date | airline | flightType | price | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 11-20-2020 10:23 | 1 | 1 | 120 | Eur |
| 2 | 1 | 11-21-2020 10:24 | 1 | 2 | 110 | CHF |
| 3 | 2 | 11-01-2020 11:25 | 2 | 2 | 120 | Eur |
| 4 | 1 | 15-01-2020 10:23 | 1 | 1 | 100 | Eur |
| 5 | 1 | 11-01-2020 11:23 | 1 | 2 | 60 | Eur |
| 6 | 1 | 12-01-2020 10:23 | 1 | 3 | 35 | Eur |

**airline :**

| id | airline |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | French |
| 2 | Swiss |

**type :**

| id | flightType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | domestic |
| 2 | international |

Now the data we are trying to figure out is number of bookings consecutively within x days (let say if two days it would mean how many bookings were made in 2 days) for various parameters like

- airline
- flightType
- airline & flightype
- currency
- price total price

For example lets say I wish to see what is the percentage of  customer who have made multiple bookings within x days across multiple airline I should be able to do so or if I want to see the total revenue of customers who have made multiple booking within x days or customers who have made multiple booking with different set of currencies with x days

I am trying to make self join to extract such data and then group it but I am always reaching a dead end

```
SELECT 
    t1.customer, t1.request_date, t1.airline, count(*)
    FROM booking t1 
    JOIN booking t2 
    ON t1.customer= t2.customer
    WHERE t2.request_date > t1.request_date and DATEDIFF(t2.request_date, t1.request_date) > 0 and DATEDIFF(t2.request_date, t1.request_date) <=2
    GROUP BY t1.customer, t1.request_date
```

The problem I am facing is the date has time and it gives me wrong results. And I am not sure what is the right way to get %share of customers who make booking in such way like
% share of customers who book more than one flight / more than one type of flight within span of x days.

Sorry if the question is too vague or if this violates any rules.
By the way I am using mysql 5.5

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you show the result that you're getting from you query? And give an example of the output you expect instead? Then explain how it's not giving you what you'd like. Can you also please limit your Question to one thing? The percentage calculation is a bit confusing. Do you want a count of the top number of bookings for a customer within x days? Or the top number compared to their total number? Or their top number compared to the other customers top numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to see the total revenue of customers who have made multiple booking within x days or customers who have made multiple booking with different set of currencies with x days

You can answer questions like this using window functions.  For the first question, this looks like:

```
select count(distinct customer)
from (select b.*,
             lag(request_date) over (partition by customer order by request_date) as prev_request_date
      from booking b
     ) b
where request_date <= prev_request_date + interval <n> day;
```

Comment: Thanks but this is giving me error select COUNT(distinct customer)
from (select booking.*,
             lag(request_date) over (partition by customer order by request_date) as prev_request_date from booking
     ) booking
where request_date <= prev_request_date + 2;      heck the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by customer order by request_date) as prev_request_date from booking

Comment: @SandeepNair . . . MySQL has supported window functions for several years.  Perhaps you should think about upgrading to a more recent version.